# Does Asterisk Server have Stun and Turn Servers implemented

Tags: asterisk

I have a problem with NAT traversal. I wan't to use Asterisk server but I do not know if it has support for TURN and STUN protocols, or he cand be configured as a STUN and TURN Server.

Comment: belongs on superuser.com

Answer (score 4):

While this does probably belong on superuser...

Asterisk 1.8 and Asterisk 10 have res_stun_monitor.  This resource module will send STUN requests to a configured STUN server.  If a change in the external IP address or port provided by the STUN server is detected, both the IAX2 and SIP channel drivers will be notified and make use of that information.

Neither Asterisk 1.8 nor Asterisk 10 have TURN support.

Asterisk 11 will have full support for ICE, which includes support for both STUN and TURN.